# Mostrar imagem ao passar o mouse em linha de gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagem, gridview

Num site de gestão de RH, existe uma consulta de histórico de prontidão. Eis como a página foi feita:

ARQUIVO ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="historicoProntidao.aspx.cs" Inherits="historicoProntidao" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Histórico do Nível de Prontidão</title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="panelSemBorda">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imagens/Logo.png" BorderStyle="None"/>
        </div>
        <div class="titleCenter"><asp:Label ID="lblTitulo" runat="server" Text="Histórico de Prontidão"></asp:Label></div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">&nbsp;</div>
<br /><br /><br />
</div>
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Items><asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/loginAvaliacoes.aspx" Text="Sair" Value="Sair"/></Items>
        <Items><asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/home.aspx" Text="Voltar para Gestão de RH" Value="Voltar para Gestão de RH"/></Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
</div>
<div align="center" class="central">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <uc:messagebox ID="mbxGeral" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCodigoColaboradorAvaliador" runat="server" />
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" border="0">

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblFiltrosPesquisa" runat="server" Text="Selecione o a unidade/corporativo para visualizar a evolução dos colaboradores disponíveis para avaliar:"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="visibility:hidden">
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblPeriodoAvaliacao" runat="server" Text="Período de avaliação:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPeriodoAvaliacao" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlPeriodoAvaliacao_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Selecione o período de avaliação" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblUnidadeEmpresa" runat="server" Text="Unidade/Corporativo:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUnidade" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Selecione a unidade" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="pesquisar" ID="rfvUnidade" runat="server" ErrorMessage="obrigatório preenchimento da unidade/corporativo" ControlToValidate="ddlUnidade" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <ajaxtoolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="rfvUnidade" Enabled="True"></ajaxtoolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lkbPesquisar" runat="server" Text="Pesquisar" onclick="lkbPesquisar_Click" ValidationGroup="pesquisar"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gwColaboradores" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#E74310" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="codigoColaboradorAvaliado" HeaderText="Código" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cargo" HeaderText="Cargo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="codigoUnidade" HeaderText="Código Unidade" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Setor" HeaderText="Setor" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="anoAvaliacao" HeaderText="Ano da Avaliação" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalFinal" HeaderText="Total Final (%)" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="{0:F2}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Resultado" HeaderText="Resultado" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNaoEncontrado" runat="server" Text="Não foram encontrados resultados" Visible="false" CssClass="mensagemErro"></asp:Label>
                    <br /><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            <asp:Image ID="NineBoxDiv" runat="server" ImageUrl="imagens/NineBox.png" BorderStyle="None" Visible="false" />

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPeriodoAvaliacao" />
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <ajaxtoolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdatePanel1" BehaviorID="animation">
        <Animations>
            <OnUpdating><FadeOut minimumOpacity="0.3" /></OnUpdating>
            <OnUpdated><FadeIn minimumOpacity="0.3" /></OnUpdated>
        </Animations>
        </ajaxtoolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
</div>
<div class="clear hideSkiplink"><br /></div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ARQUIVO ASPX.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class historicoProntidao : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["usuario"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?session=0");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Classes.colaborador colaborador = (Classes.colaborador)Session["usuario"];
        hfCodigoColaboradorAvaliador.Value = colaborador.codigo.ToString();
        atualizaUnidades(hfCodigoColaboradorAvaliador.Value, "5");
    }
}
private void atualizaUnidades(string codigoColaborador, string codigoAvaliacao)
{
    if (codigoColaborador!= "" && codigoAvaliacao != "")
    {
        Classes.colaborador colaborador = (Classes.colaborador)Session["usuario"];
        if (colaborador.avaliaTodasUnidades)
            ddlUnidade.DataSource = Classes.unidade.consultaUnidadeAvaliacao("", int.Parse(codigoAvaliacao));
        else
            ddlUnidade.DataSource = Classes.unidade.consultaUnidadeAvaliacao(codigoColaborador, int.Parse(codigoAvaliacao));

        ddlUnidade.DataValueField = "codigo";
        ddlUnidade.DataTextField = "descricao";
        ddlUnidade.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ddlUnidade.Items.Clear();
        ddlUnidade.Items.Add("Selecione a unidade");
    }
}
protected void lkbPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool gerencia = false;
    bool coordenador = false;
    bool analista = false;
    int codigo = int.Parse(hfCodigoColaboradorAvaliador.Value);
    int codigoUnidade = int.Parse(ddlUnidade.SelectedItem.Value);
    //int codigoPeriodo = int.Parse(ddlPeriodoAvaliacao.SelectedItem.Value);
    Classes.colaborador colaborador = (Classes.colaborador)Session["usuario"];
    DataTable dt = Classes.cargo.consultaCargoColaborador(codigo);
    DataTable dtColaboradores = null;

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gerencia = dt.Rows[0]["cargoGerencia"].ToString() == "False" ? false : true;
        coordenador = dt.Rows[0]["cargoCoordenador"].ToString() == "False" ? false : true;
        analista = dt.Rows[0]["cargoAnalista"].ToString() == "False" ? false : true;

        if (gerencia || colaborador.avaliaTodasUnidades)
            dtColaboradores = Classes.colaborador.consultaColaboradorProntidao(codigoUnidade);
        else
        {
            if (coordenador)
                dtColaboradores = Classes.colaborador.consultaColaboradorProntidao(codigoUnidade);
        }
    }
    gwColaboradores.DataSource = dtColaboradores;
    gwColaboradores.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    gwColaboradores.Columns[1].Visible = true;
    gwColaboradores.Columns[2].Visible = true;
    gwColaboradores.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    gwColaboradores.Columns[4].Visible = true;
    gwColaboradores.Columns[5].Visible = true;
    gwColaboradores.Columns[6].Visible = true;
    gwColaboradores.Columns[7].Visible = true;
    gwColaboradores.DataBind();
}
protected void ddlPeriodoAvaliacao_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    atualizaUnidades(hfCodigoColaboradorAvaliador.Value, ddlPeriodoAvaliacao.SelectedItem.Value);
}
}
```

A consulta funciona perfeitamente, trazendo sempre uma Gridview com os dados da pessoa e o resultado de avaliações que foram realizadas (entre 0 e 100%).

Mas eu queria que fossem mostradas diferentes imagens quando eu passo o mouse por cima das linhas da Gridview. Por exemplo, entre 0 e 20%, é uma imagem. Entre 20 e 40% é outra imagem. E por aí vai. Acredito que o recurso a ser usado é o onmouseover.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Cria uma propriedade oculta e popula de acordo com a percentagem. Quando utilizar o mouseover pega essa propriedade para mostrar a imagem.

Comment: @Denis Como eu coloco isso em código? Já pesquisei em alguns sites mas não consegui nada parecido.

Comment: Cria a coluna para a propriedade e seta como hidden:

<asp:BoundField DataField="propriedadeParaIndicarImagem" />

Cria a propriedade "propriedadeParaIndicarImagem" na classe "colaborador" e popula com o indicador antes de settar o dtColaboradores.

Sobre mostrar a imagem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678846/display-image-on-mouse-hover-in-gridview-row

ou

http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/127988/Display-Image-on-GridView-Row-MouseOver-Mouse-Hover-in-ASPNet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gustavo, fiz um exemplo, olha só:

**ASPX**

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gwColaboradores" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#E74310" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
        <Columns>                
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Avaliacao" HeaderText="Avaliação (%)" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                    HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />                
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**CODE-BEHIND**

```
public class Colaborador
{
    public int Avaliacao { get; set; }

    public Colaborador(int avaliacao)
    {
        Avaliacao = avaliacao;
    }
}

public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Colaborador> lista = new List<Colaborador>();
        lista.Add(new Colaborador(17));
        lista.Add(new Colaborador(37));
        lista.Add(new Colaborador(78));

        gwColaboradores.DataSource = lista;
        gwColaboradores.DataBind();
    }

}
```

**O código html gerado é esse aqui:**

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gwColaboradores" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="color:White;background-color:#E74310;">
        <th align="center" scope="col">Avaliação (%)</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center">87</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center">37</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center">78</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Com isso criei o JsFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigorf/Lo734r51/2/) para testar com Jquery como exibir imagens diferentes a partir dos valores da coluna de avaliação:

```
var imgPath = "";
 var avaliacao = $(this).html();
 if(Number(avaliacao) > 50)
 {
     imgPath = "https://vc.vse.cz/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Accept-icon.png";
 }else
 {
     imgPath = "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hospital-and-medical-v2/512/danger_poison_venom_toxic-128.png";
 }
```

Então ao passar o mouse por cima de uma linha, pega o valor da coluna avaliacao e testa uma faixa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro caminho seria, ter a imagem(path) no objeto Colaborador, no RowDatabound do grid fazer o teste do if para saber o valor da avaliação e atribuir a imagem que desejar para o atributo imagem do Colaborador. Mas isso depende de você, se fosse a foto do colaborador até faz sentido mas se a imagem que você for exibir é apenas uma funcionalidade de frontend faz mais sentido ter tudo no javascript. Como vi que seu COlaborador não tem a url da imagem escolhi o caminho do javascript